# Gulp, browserify to use react as CommonJS not working. React is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I have been trying to bundle ReactJS as a commonJS module using browserify and gulp but whenever i run my code, I get a **React is not defined error** and being new to this, i haven't been able to find a proper solution to this error.

Here is what the part with browserify looks like

```
gulp.task('build', function(){
  browserify({
    entries: [path.ENTRY_POINT],
    transform: [reactify],
  }).require('react')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(path.MINIFIED_OUT))
    .pipe(streamify(uglify(path.MINIFIED_OUT)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_BUILD));
});
```

I have checked the bundle file generated and React is defined at the bottom of the page, not sure if that is supposed to mean anything but this is how i am calling React in my app.js file.

```
    var React  = require('react');
    var Parent = require('./parent.js');
    React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What is it that i need to do right to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the example it includes the react library on the builded file, if you want to remove it use browserify-shim.

Gulpfile.js (task)

```
browserify('index.js', {
    debug: true,
    transform: ['babelify', 'reactify2']
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

package.json (devDependencies)

```
   "react": "^0.13.1",
```

Comment: i use babelify too, but this is not needed